# parsing json with gson in java

Tags: java, json, gson, reddit

I'm trying to parse [this json](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/new.json) and crate a POJO from it. The online documentation has me confused. I suspect I am incorrectly handling the fact that there are many different occurances of the same type of object. Do I need an array? What would that look like? Here is my class so far:

```
public class StoryGSONClass {
private Response kind;

public static class Response {
    private String Listing;
    private Data data;
}

public static class Data {
    private String modhash;
    private Children children;
    private String after;
    private String before;
}

public static class Children {
    private String childKind;
    private ChildData childData;
}

public static class ChildData {
    private String domain;
    private String banned_by;
    private String media_embed;
    private String subreddit;
    private String selftext_html;
    private String selftext;
    private String likes;
    private String link_flair_text;
    private String id;
    private String clicked;
    private String title;
    private String num_comments;
    private String score;
    private String approved_by;
    private String over_18;
    private String hidden;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String subreddit_id;
    private String edited;
    private String link_flair_css_class;
    private String author_flair_css_class;
    private String downs;
    private String saved;
    private String is_self;
    private String permalink;
    private String name;
    private String created;
    private String url;
    private String author_flair_text;
    private String author;
    private String created_utc;
    private String media;
    private String num_reports;
    private String ups;
}
```

}

followed by

```
Gson gson = new Gson();    
StoryGSONClass target2 = gson.fromJson(objectName, StoryGSONClass.class);
```

Edit: here is the newest version of the class:

```
public class Response {
    private String kind;
    private ResponseData data;

public static class ResponseData {
    private String modhash;
    private List<ResponseChildData> children;
    private String after;
    private String before;
}

public static class ResponseChildData {
    private String kind;
    private ChildData data;
}

public static class ChildData {
    private String domain;
    private String banned_by;
    private Object media_embed;
    private String subreddit;
    private String selftext_html;
    private String selftext;
    private String likes;
    private String link_flair_text;
    private String id;
    private boolean clicked;
    private String title;
    private int num_comments;
    private int score;
    private String approved_by;
    private boolean over_18;
    private boolean hidden;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String subreddit_id;
    private boolean edited;
    private boolean link_flair_css_class;
    private boolean author_flair_css_class;
    private int downs;
    private boolean saved;
    private boolean is_self;
    private String permalink;
    private String name;
    private String created;
    private String url;
    private String author_flair_text;
    private String author;
    private String created_utc;
    private String media;
    private String num_reports;
    private int ups;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main parent object should look something like this:

```
public class Response {
    private String kind;
    private ResponseData data;

    ...
}
```

Then `ResponseData` is:

```
public class ResponseData {
    private String modhash;
    private List<ResponseChildData> children; // I imagine this is where you're having
                                              // some confusion. You can use a list here
                                              // and you should be fine.

    ...
}
```

And `ResponseChildData` is:

```
public class ResponseChildData {
    private String kind;
    private ChildData data; // This could be a Map<String, String>, but then you'd
                            // possibly lose type information. I haven't used GSON 
                            // enough to know if it would balk when it sees that some
                            // values are int and boolean and refuse to deserialize.
                            // Using a specific type here is probably better anyway

    ...
}
```

Finally, `ChildData` is:

```
public class ChildData {
    private String domain;
    private String banned_by;
    ...
    ...
    private int ups;

    ...
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();    
Response target2 = gson.fromJson(objectName, Response.class);
```

Comment: I have updated the class. When children is returned empty then everything goes fine and I can access things like data.modhash . But when children comes back non-empty I get a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at..." error.

Comment: That's because you've incorrectly specified that the value for that attribute is a `String` when it should be an object. Instead of seeing a string (i.e., something that starts with `"`), Gson is seeing the start of an object (i.e., it is seeing a `{`).